# Pandas failure in creating date time objects from list of strings while row iteration

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HuSj.png)I have a pandas dataframe that has a column contains lists of dates formatted as strings, something like:
['2019-08-19', '2018-04-23']

I am trying to convert these lists into a list of DateTime objects such that I can compare these dates with dates from another column that has similar formatting, iteratively through df.iterrows().

I tried something like:

#

```
<i>for index, row in merged_list.iterrows():`enter code here`
    scs_date = list(row["scs_date"])
    print(scs_date) 
    print(type(scs_date))
    l1 = pd.to_datetime(row["scs_date"]).dt.date.unique().tolist()<i>
```

#

But it keeps splitting the lists into individual characters and complains that it cannot convert the items into date-time objects.

I also tried:

```
l1 = [datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d").date() for date in scs_date]
```

And again it did not work and gave me this error:

"ValueError: time data '[' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'"
    enter code here

Any clue,
Thanks

UPDATE:

I have added a sample dataframe if it can be of help.
The ultimate goal is to find out if any date from DAY_1 column exists in DAY_2 column of the same row. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HuSj.png

Answer (score 0):

It would benefit you to post what your data actually looks like.

```
df =pd.DataFrame(
    [[['2019-08-19', '2018-04-23']],
     [['2019-08-19', '2018-04-23']],
     [['2019-08-19', '2018-04-23']],
     [['2019-08-19', '2018-04-23']]])


def f(v):
    return [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in v]

df[0] = df[0].map(f)
print(df)
                                            0
0  [2019-08-19 00:00:00, 2018-04-23 00:00:00]
1  [2019-08-19 00:00:00, 2018-04-23 00:00:00]
2  [2019-08-19 00:00:00, 2018-04-23 00:00:00]
3  [2019-08-19 00:00:00, 2018-04-23 00:00:00]
```

Comment: Thanks manwithfewneeds. I tried the code but got this error:ValueError: time data '[' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'....I think for some reason Pandas identifies the whole list as one long string..I also tried to delete the ' from the cells through string deletion, but this did not help..I have included a sample image of the dataframe and added an update for the proplem..I really appreciate if you can comment on that.

Comment: That's because what you think might look like a list is actually a string. You'll need to str.strip to get out those brackets and do a str.split on the commas to get a list